# How can I combine these two formulas?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18eH6APJwbV8x6iDpVxia-m1Ge90cIjC0Nu4QmEmbrM0/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to combine these two formulas but can't seem to the ' and " right?

I want to output a table that has the data from the source tables whose sheet name is checked in sheet `FL-elever`:

- Formulas to join:

[image]

- Checked names to filter:

[image]

- Source tables format:

[image]

Comment: What formulas are you talking about?

Comment: Take a look at Desired output-sheet

Comment: Can you explain what is the desired output?

Comment: 1st formula check checked names in Names-sheet.
2nd formula displays a merged view from three *Prename*-sheets.
What I am trying to do is to make the 2nd formula dynamic so only checked names are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with an Apps Script [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, and copy the following function to the script (check inline comments):

```js
function POPULATE_TABLE() {
  var output = new Array(6).fill("").map(function() { 
    return new Array(5).fill(""); // Initialize the 2D array you will output
  });
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Get the rows in which checkbox is marked:
  var FLelever = ss.getSheetByName("FL-elever");
  var checkedNames = FLelever.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1).filter(function(row) {
    return row[5] === true;
  });
  checkedNames.forEach(function(checkedName) { // Iterate through each row with marked checkbox
    var sheetName = checkedName[0] + "-" + checkedName[1]; // Get sheet name (column A + "-" + column B)
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Get corresponding sheet
    if (sheet) { // Check that sheet exists
      // Get the source table from the corresponding sheet:
      var firstRow = 2;
      var firstCol = 2;
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
      var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn() - firstRow + 1;
      var values = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
      // Iterate through the source table and add the existing values to output:
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (output[i][j] !== "" && values[i][j] !== "") {
            output[i][j] = output[i][j].concat(", ");
          }
          output[i][j] = output[i][j].concat(values[i][j]); // Concatenate values
        }
      }
    }    
  });
  return output;
}
```

Once it is defined, you can use this function the same you would any sheets built-in function:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: OK - I have tried your scripted solution and even though it works it's way too complicated for me and this project. I will ofc honor your answer but I'm far from my desired output. I will add a new - altered - question.